# Conditional expectation derivation of proof

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, conditional-expectation

very basic question on the derivation of the conditional expectation formula for a continuous random variable. I get the intuition for the formula, but not one crucial step.

starting from $E[X|Y] = \int x f_{X|Y}(x|y) dx = \int x \frac {f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)}{f_{Y}(y)} dx $

I know that we are suppose to end up with $E[X|Y] = \int x \frac {f_X(x)}{f_{Y}(y)} dx = \frac {E[X]}{P(Y)}$

I am wondering why $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = 1$? is it because as we condition on the whole range of X, then it just collapses to 1?

to give a specific example:

why is it that: for $\theta \sim U[-1,1]$, and $a\in [-1,1]$

$E[\theta | \theta > a] = \frac{\int_{a}^1 \theta f(\theta)d\theta}{1-F(a)} $

?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, then $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is not a real number like $E[X]$ - rather, it is a random variable itself. Indeed, $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is the unique $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable which satisfies
$$ \int_A \mathbb E[X\mid Y]\ \mathsf d\mathbb P = \int_A X \mathsf d\mathbb P $$ for all $A\in\sigma(G)$.

Comment: The expression $\mathbb E[\theta\mid\theta>a]$, however, *is* a real number (assuming $\theta$ is integrable), and $$\mathbb E[\theta\mid\theta>a] = \frac{\mathbb E\left[\theta\mathsf 1_{\{\theta > a\}}\right]}{\mathbb P(\theta>a)}.$$

Comment: @Math1000 thank you very much! yes it makes more sense to me with the indicator function in front. 
just one detail: suppose I want to evaluate $E[\theta | \theta > 1 - b]$ with $b \in (0,1)$, I would then have:
$P(\theta > 1-b) = 1-b/2$ and
$E[\theta | \theta > 1-b] = \int_{1-b}^1 \frac{1}{2} \theta d\theta = \frac{1}{4}(2b-b^2)$ 
right?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that we are suppose to end up with ...

That's where you are going wrong. You aren't supposed to end with that. You are missing an indicator random variable, and this only holds when $Y$ is discrete. That is that the event $Y=y$ has non-zero probability *mass*.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid Y=y) =& \int_\Bbb R x~f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)~\mathsf d x \\[1ex] = & \int_\Bbb R \frac{x~f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}~\mathsf d x\\[2ex] =& \dfrac{\int_\Bbb R x~f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathsf d x}{\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(y)~\mathsf d x}\\[2ex] =& \dfrac{\sum_{k}\int_\Bbb R x\mathbf 1_{k=y}~f_{X,Y}(x,k)~\mathsf d x}{\sum_{k}\int_\Bbb R \mathbf 1_{k=y}~f_{X,Y}(x,k)~\mathsf d x} &\text{if $Y$ is a discrete random variable} \\[2ex] =& \dfrac{\mathsf E(X~\mathbf 1_{Y=y})}{\mathsf P(Y=y)} \end{align}$$

If $Y$ is continuous, then you should stop at line 1 or 2.

---

So likewise:

If the event $\theta>a$ has non-zero probability mass, (and $a$ is constant, $\theta$ a random variable) then: $$\mathsf E(\theta\mid\theta>a) = \dfrac{\mathsf E(\theta~\mathbf 1_{\theta>a})}{\mathsf P(\theta>a)}$$

Comment: thank you very much @GrahamKemp for your answer! yes it makes more sense to me with the indicator function in front. just one detail: suppose I want to evaluate $E[\theta | \theta > 1 - b]$ with $b \in (0,1)$, I would then have:
$P(\theta > 1-b) = 1-b/2$ and
$E[\theta | \theta > 1-b] = \int_{1-b}^1 \frac{1}{2} \theta d\theta = \frac{1}{4}(2b-b^2)$ 
right?